# Php file download from database returning html not actual file

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, blob

I'm trying to download files from my database whose data is stored as a blob. However, my code constantly returns a html file instead of the actual file.

What's worse, the output is given the name 'handleDownload' which is the name of my php download script and not the actual file name!

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

This is the tutorial that I've been following: http://www.w3programmers.com/file-upload-and-download-with-php/

Download codes

```
<?php 
$Download = new Download();
$result = array(); //store results of output
try {
    //if id is set then get file from database
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      //pump id in to function getDBFiles to pull file with matching id
      $Download->getDBFiles($id);
      //get array containing file details from function getDBFiles
      $getFiles = $Download->getMessages();
      $size = $getFiles['size'];
      $type = $getFiles['type'];
      $name = $getFiles['name'];
      $content = $getFiles['content'];
      header("Content-length: $size");
      header("Content-type: $type");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
      echo $content; exit;
    }
    //execute retrieval of files from database
    $Download->showDBFiles();
    //pass results to output array 
    $output = $Download->getMessages();
    //var_dump($output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result[] = $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Database codes

```
 protected $messages = array();
 public function showDBFiles() {
     global $database;
     $sql = "SELECT resume_id, resume_title FROM ".self::$table_name;
     $result = $database->query($sql);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
         $this->messages[] = "Database is empty";
     }else{
           while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  $this->messages[] = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name);
          }

    }
}

public function getDBFiles($id) {
    global $database;
    $sql = "SELECT resume_title, file_type, file_size,resume_data FROM  ".self::$table_name." WHERE resume_id = $id";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $this->messages[] = array('name'=>$name, 'type'=>$type, 'size'=>$size, 'content'=>$content);        
        }

public function getMessages()
{
  return $this->messages;
}
```